# Cannot pair HM10 BLE 4.0 module from Android phone

Tags: bluetooth

I am currently learning Arduino Bluetooth connectivity with a HM-10S module.
I did some sample tutorial code and it works only with LightBlue app.

However, when I use the default Bluetooth pairing function from the android phone(samsung S10 plus), it seems failed to pair or connect.

So here is the cases I tried:

**Android App(LightBlue and also Arduino Bluetooth Controller) :**

Success connection without entering password.

**Windows 10 PC:**

Success pairing only by entering password: "123456", but no com port added

**Android phone(S10 plus) Default pairing method from setting**

Entered "123456" as password to pair, then no response.

So, what puzzles me is:

1. I can connect with some apps and do my work, without pairing using Android's setting utility; Is that implies establishing a connection for further action does not necessary to firstly getting things paired?
2. There are no com port installed after I paired the bt module, so it probably mean the module does not provide my desired feature. If that's the case, which BT module is recommended?

Great thanks if somebody could give me some ideas.

Comment: I tried a while ago to connect my HC-06 bluetooth module zo my andriod smartphone. The imortant bit, which I couldnt find anywhere described is, that the pairing doesn't really build up the connection. It sets the settings for the connection and then closes it. I always needed an app (either a bluetooth serial terminal app  or my own self written app) initiating and holding the actual connection. And that makes kind of sense. Where should Andriod send the data, when you don't use it anywhere? Why would it hild the connection then?

Comment: On Windows I guess it just creates a serial COM port, which is independent there, even if you don't read it.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this also applies to the HM-10S, but it might very well. What are you actually trying, that you want to connect without an app running the connection?

Comment: While I did compare the HM10 to HC-06, they are still different technologies and they don't need to behave the same. The HM10 is Bluetooth 4 BLE. It seems it can have different characteristics, also depending on the firmware. When the serial com port characteristic is not active, no com port will show up. Unfortunately I don't have enough experience with the HM10 to guide you there. I have just googled for "HM10 serial bridge" and found [this blog entry](https://www.shortn0tes.com/2017/08/uart-bridge-from-hm-10-to-pc-with-java.html). Maybe it helps. Otherwise you should try similar searches.